# Passing node value to downstream job on the run

Tags: jenkins

I have two freestyle jobs say JOB1(upstream job) and JOB2(downstream job). JOB1 has to be run on master while JOB2 to be run on slaves.Job2 is parameterized with nodes.I have 3 nodes.
When i run JOB1 it triggers JOB2 but JOB2 remains Pending showing it doen not match any nodes.
How can i pass the node value to JOB2 on the run? I mean when i run JOB1 either it ask for NODE values to pass onto JOB2 or I set some key value pairs so that it takes accordingly on which node to run upon.
Any help or clue would be great.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in two ways i.e for providing node label manually Just add the choice parameter in the JOB1 then in post build action use parameterized trigger plugin and add the project which is JOB2 then add the node label parameter put $NODE_NAME.
Note-NODE_NAME is taken from  name field in choice parameter step.
Now at the time of build of JOB1 it will ask for which node to build upon the JOB2.

To know how can we pass the node variables at runtime i.e it will select based on properties file which node to select using script,PLEASE FEEL FREE TO COMMENT.